# Any unique interactions, with an Altmer Dragonborn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It's admittedly been a while since I was last able to play Skyrim, so I was wanting to ask here: are there any unique interactions (such as dialogue or options in quests) in the game, depending on if the Dragonborn is specifically an Altmer/High Elf?

With the Thalmor looming over everyone, for one thing, I feel there could be - but I unfortunately can't remember, other than I think there was a unique disguise option at a point in one quest?

Answer (score 3):

Other than the disguise option in *Diplomatic Immunity* it makes no difference whatsoever, and that is quite limited too, to quote the UESP wiki:

> If you play as an Altmer, it's even possible to tell the wizard guarding the door to the Solar that 'Elenwen wants to see him' by passing a speech check, thus allowing free access to the Solar (if you cannot pass the speech check however, he'll notice that you're an intruder and everybody in the courtyard will turn hostile). Note that once you reach Elenwen's Solar, the patrolling guard, as well as Rulindil, are scripted to see through your disguise, regardless of race.

Another tidbit: the disguise only works with *Hooded Thalmor Robes*.

Comment: There are several places in the game where dialogue depends on the player's race, starting from right after the cart ride in Helgen. None of it has a gameplay impact, though.

Comment: And according to this [thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/615804-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/61271615#5), "High elves are attacked on sight by Orc strongholds".